# Don`t work HQL queries in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am using Java 9, Hibernate 5, PostgreSQL 10 and I have been trying to do some HQL queries with database.

This method works:

```
public List<MP3> getAll(String name) {
    query = session.createQuery( "from " + name);
    List mp3 = query.list();
    return mp3;
}
```

But, this  method does not  work:

```
public void deleteByName(String name) {
        String hql = "DELETE MP3  where name = :name";
        query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("name",name);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

My StackTrace is as follows:

```
08:31:54.292 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections.access - HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@401317a0] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
08:31:54.308 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        MP3 
    where
        name=?
08:31:54.386 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres]
```

Please help me in solving  the issue.

Comment: The first query is a `SELECT` which does not need a transaction, but the seconds one is a `DELETE` which does need a transaction

Comment: I tried, but didn`t work
public void deleteByName(String name) {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "DELETE MP3  where name = :name";
        query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("name",name);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }

Comment: where is the commit?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Are you sure you're passing a correct parameter? If you don't get an exception and nothing happens, that's the most likely reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@Transactional` to the method :

```
@Transactional
public void deleteByName(String name) {
    String hql = "DELETE MP3  where name = :name";
    query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("name",name);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Cheers, Happy Coding... Don't forget to accept the answer as solution and upvote if possible.

Comment: Nothing above say this is executed in JEE environment